# CS5+AS3 Preloader starts at 50%; no clue why

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader, flash-cs5

I know there are a lot of previous topics about preloaders and I've tried to follow every one of them but I still get the same problem (well they have helped me go from 80% -> 50%)
Right now it starts at `61450 / 125207` which is about 50%.

Here is my `Main Document` (default class file for the entire project) class:

```
public class MainDocument extends MovieClip
{
    private var preloader:Preloader;
    private var sB:startButton;
    public function MainDocument() 
    {
        preloader = new Preloader();
        preloader.x = 300;
        preloader.y = 400;
        addChild(preloader);
        loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,addStartButton,false,0,true);
    }
    private function addStartButton(e:Event):void
    {
        sB = new startButton();
        sB.x = 300;
        sB.y = 450;
        sB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,sMainMenu,false,0,true);
        addChild(sB);
        loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,addStartButton);
    }
    private function sMainMenu(e:Event):void
    {
        sB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,sMainMenu);
        removeChild(sB);
        removeChild(preloader);
        sB = null;
        preloader = null;           
        var menuScreen = new MenuScreen();
        addChild(menuScreen);

        //I have heard that the following code might work better:
        //var menuScreen:Class = getDefinitionByName("MenuScreen") as Class;
        //addChild(new menuScreen() as DisplayObject);
    }
}
```

And the `Preloader` that it attaches:

```
public class Preloader extends MovieClip
{
    public function Preloader()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Load);
    }
    private function Load(e:Event):void
    {
        //"bar" is a movieclip inside the preloader object
        bar.scaleX = loaderInfo.bytesLoaded/loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
        //"percent" is a dynamic text inside the preloader object
        percent.text = Math.floor(loaderInfo.bytesLoaded/loaderInfo.bytesTotal*100)﻿+"%";
        trace(loaderInfo.bytesLoaded+" / "+loaderInfo.bytesTotal);
        if (loaderInfo.bytesLoaded == loaderInfo.bytesTotal)
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Load);
        }
    }
}
```

**-> Nothing is set to `Export on Frame 1` except for the `Preloader`**

**-> No objects exist on the first frame; the only code on first frame is `stop();`**

**-> I placed a copy of every single MovieClip in the second frame and when the startButton is clicked, a `gotoAndStop(3);` is run so no one ever sees frame 2.**

If anyone knows of anything simple that I could have forgotten, please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Anything in the stage on Frame 1 is exported on Frame 1, regardless of settings. TextField included, its font included.

Comment: why is the preloader on enterFrame, single function is fine.

Comment: `@Vesper` Nothing is on the stage on Frame 1. Should I have the preloader on Frame 1 instead of adding it via MainDocument? `@joshua` If I put the Load() method as my constructor, I get an error that I am accessing null properties (bar & percent)

Comment: Sounds like your problem is caused by too much stuff being included in first frame of swf (by compiler if not by you directly). Do you have any library assets set to "Export for ActionScript"? If so, you'll need to untick "Export in frame 1"

Comment: `@Lee` I have 3 main bold points for common things that people do not usually do when they have preloader issue. Bold point #1 says `Nothing is set to Export on Frame 1 except the Preloader` movieclip. Maybe I am referencing too many things some where in which case it has to be loaded later on. But I put everything in the second frame (so flash loads it later AFTER first frame, the preloader) and I could use `getDefinitionByName` instead but it actually seemed to make the whole thing start later by about 0.2% (the code that is in comment section of the `MainDocument` class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Lee Burrows` What you said was right but would have been better if you looked at what I mentioned at the end of the code (three bold points)

The solution I used was:
-> I set everything to `Export on Frame 2` on my 3 frame document.
-> Removed everything on Frame 2
-> Created a `TextField` via constructor and used `drawRectangle` for loading bar
-> No movieclips present on frame 1, and used

```
var menuScreen:Class = getDefinitionByName("MenuScreen") as Class;
addChild(new menuScreen() as DisplayObject);
```

instead of the previous code.

The reason why what I had originally didn't work because, as `Lee Burrows` mentioned, the `Export for Actionscript` hangs the loading if `X = 1` in `Export on Frame X`, regardless if `Export on Frame 1` was checked or not. Changing it to 2 or unchecking `Export for Actionscript` were the two solutions (except if it isn't exported for actionscript, then its code cant be referenced to).

Preloader starts at about 2% now.

Answer (score 1):

You're tying to use a preloader in the file being preloaded.  In that case, there is going to be bloat from the rest of the project's code and assets.  The reason you are seeing your preloader seemingly delayed is because a swf must load completely before any code will execute.  This includes all assets on stage regardless of what frame they are on, even if you have settings in place to export on something other than frame 1.  Instead, try using a blank shell as your preloader.  This shell will have nothing in it but the loader code and a preloader graphic or animation.  When the load is finished, hide your preloader and add your loaded content to the stage of the shell, or a container movieclip in the shell.

All the following code goes in your shell, which is just another FLA file with nothing in it but this code, and a preloader bar.  The dimensions of this file should be the same as the file you are loading into it, ie your original swf file you were trying to preload.

Use it by calling **loadSwf( "mySwfNameOrURLToSwf.swf" );**
The variable **_percent** will populate with the current load percentage, which you can correspond to your loading bar scale.  Presuming the preloader bar is named "bar", the line **bar.visible = false;** in the onSwfLoaded function will hide it.  **addChild( _swf )** adds the loaded swf to the shell's stage.  The line **_swf.init();** references a function in the loaded swf you will need to add called **init()** that starts your loaded swf doing whatever it is its supposed to do.  Have everything in the loaded swf start on the first frame now, including the **init()** function.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

import flash.net.URLRequest;

import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.system.Security;

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

var _swfLoader:Loader;
var _swf:DisplayObject;
var _percent:Number;

function loadSwf( swfURL:String ):void
{
    _swfLoader = new Loader();
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest( swfURL );

    var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
    loaderContext.checkPolicyFile = true;

    _swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onSwfProgress);
    _swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoaded);

    _swfLoader.load(req, loaderContext);
}

function onSwfProgress( evt:Event ):void
{
    _percent = Math.round( ( evt.target.bytesLoaded / evt.target.bytesTotal ) * 100 );
}

function onSwfLoaded( evt:Event ):void
{
    _swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onSwfProgress);
    _swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoaded);

    _swf = _swfLoader.content;

    addChild( _swf );
    bar.visible = false;
    _swf.init();

    _swfLoader = null;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not that advanced yet. What do you mean by `shell` (how do I make one)?

Comment: Is this the only workaround for preloaders? I really really wanted an internal preloader so that it would only be 1 file (which is what many sites accept; not multi-files). Unless I'm wrong and this method can still be done with only 1 file... o.O

Comment: Its not a "work-around", this is how you would properly handle this scenario.  In the case of a site only accepting one file, you would host the supporting files for your game/app/banner somewhere, likely your own server.  The shell swf I described above would be what you give to the website, and that shell would load in your content from your server.  That way you can make bug fixes and updates to your app without having to re-traffic the application every time you do so.  In short, no, there is no way to avoid what you are seeing if you include your preloader in the same swf as the content.

Comment: I still believe it is a work-around. Since there haven't been any other answers, it seems that it is not possible to `addChild` my preloader without it getting stuck in the 30~50% range. Instead, I just created a `new TextField` and `drawRectangle` the loading bar. That way, I have been able to start preloader at about 2%. Thanks for your time in considering another possibility though.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks ok.
when you are not on a http server, loading process are simulated.

After compiling, press crtl + B.
In menu you can choose the downloading speed and simulate a download by pressing again ctrl+enter.

it might help you to debug your preloader

Comment: I have done that. I set it to about `9.1 Kb/sec` and I still get a white box (no movie loaded) and until about halfway in, the trace method of my preloader runs as soon as the first frame loads and it is at 50% (60000/120000)